# Drupal 7: Content "staggered" in page created by view

Tags: drupal, view

I have created a content type with the following fields in it:

- Image
- Title
- Body

The body field contains lists of links to pages on my site

I then created a view to list the content vertically on a page.

An example of the content can be found here:

http://www.faithmov.com/drupal/content/development-doctrine#overlay-context=frontpage-articles

When the page is opened the records on the page are "staggered" as you can see here:

http://www.faithmov.com/drupal/frontpage-articles#overlay-context=content/development-doctrine

How can I cure this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use views to display the nodes?

If that is the case use can add the following row class `clearfix` to format > settings. That should solve it.

**Explanation:**
A floating image does not count in the div height, therefor the next div starts under the div, but not under the image. clearfix is a drupal class that inserts `clear: both` to all objects it is applied to (in this case all views rows).

When you clear a div, it wraps under the largest floating object.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks for quick reply. It works perfectly. Also appreciate the explanation

Comment: No problem :) Remember to accept the answer so the question won't appear as unanswered on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Hi,One thing I have noticed. When I try to validate the page usinghttp://validator.w3.org/nu/ I find I get the error:    IO Error: <http://www.faithmov.com/drupal/frontpage-articles#overlay-context=frontpage-articles> Code: 59/PROHIBITED_COMPONENT_PRESENT in FRAGMENT: A component that is prohibited by the scheme is present. My other pages do not show this error. Can you advise why this is?